# Strategy exits at the same entry point in pine script

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

[image: See the image for more clarification]

I have tested simple moving average cross strategy with some modification. Instead of using crossover(fastEMA, slowEMA), I used fastEMA > slowEMA. When I add the strategy to the chart, strategy exits at the same entry point and the same entry bar. How can solve this problem?
Here is my code:

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)
fastEMA = ema(close, 14)
slowEMA = ema(close, 28)
longCondition = sma(close, 14) > sma(close, 28)   // crossover(fastEMA, slowEMA)
if (longCondition)
    entry = close
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("Exit long", from_entry="My Long Entry Id", limit=entry+atr(14)*3, stop=entry-atr(14)*2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this script instead.

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)

longCondition = sma(close, 14) > sma(close, 28)

if longCondition
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)

atr14 = atr(14)
float longEntry = na
float longSL = na
float longTP = na

longEntry := longCondition ? close : longEntry[1]
longSL := longCondition ? close - atr14*2 : longSL[1]
longTP := longCondition ? close + atr14*3 : longTP[1]

strategy.exit("tp or sl", "long", limit=longTP, stop=longSL)
```

Comment: Thank you so much brokeboynomore, I tested your answer and it worked :)